# Tensorflow: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been stuck on this error (for importing tensorflow) for a while, I looked on various different pages and didn't find a solution that helped. I tried installing vs 2015 as said on the internet, but that didn't work. I have downloaded python 3.8.0 rather than 3.8.2, but i still get the error. Please Help!
windows 10, latest version of tensorflow

```
    >>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\...\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.


See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Can you specify your os and TensorFlow version you are trying to install?

Comment: windows 10, latest version of tensorflow @AniketBote

Comment: After following the steps see if the issue still persists.

Comment: Sometimes [a quick diagnosis with a DLL/PYD dependency check tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64944065/tensorflow-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-pywrap-tensorflow-inter#69874313) could be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:
Using pip:
There are system requirements that I won't bother talking about all of them as they could be found on the tensorflow website, though the 3 problems I had were that:

1. I didn't install [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual
   Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).
2. Long paths weren't enabled

So just following a youtube tutorial didn't finish the problem. I had to download it based on the way on tensorflow's website.

Answer (score 1):

Create a virtual environment in python. For the creation of a virtual environment, you need virtualenv library.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

After installing create your virtual environment.
command - **virtualenv "NAME-OF-ENVIRONMENT"**

eg

```
virtualenv myenv
```

This will create a directory called myenv. To activate the virtual environment you have go inside the myenv/scripts folder, open a cmd prompt and type activate.

eg

```
cd myenv/Scripts
activate
```

Get out of the Scripts folder

```
cd ../..
```

Now install TensorFlow.

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Note: Always create a virtual environment when working in any project and keep your python package clean. You can delete these environments if they become corrupt or stop working correctly due to any reason, without and fear.

Comment: I have intel graphics, not an nvidia card

Comment: You cant use TensorFlow-GPU. If you have installed Cuda or cudnn uninstall them and follow the steps mentioned above. You can use TensorFlow-CPU which doesn't require any external setup or software. Follow the steps and see if the issue persists.

Comment: I followed the steps above and still have the same problem :(

Comment: Here is what happened, and also if you see any sensitive information please tell me so that no one does anything harmful :)
https://pastebin.com/Py3ar4dq

Comment: How was python installed?

Comment: from python.org, 3.8.0, using Windows x86-64 web-based installer

Comment: It is added to path too

Comment: Which processor are you using? Older CPU doesn't support AVX instructions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221046/discussion-between-omar-zayed-and-aniket-bote).