# TensorFlow ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, importerror, dllimport, tensorflow2.x

System specifications:

- **Python==3.8.5**
- **tensorflow==2.3.1**

I am trying to import tensorflow... but I am getting import error. Please help me rectify the problem. I tried following...

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and

```
pip install tensorflow
```

When I execute `pip freeze` I see the installed tensorflow package with specified version.
Error Message:

````
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 
     42 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use Anaconda to install Tensorflow,

Create separate environment for Tensorflow with Python 3.8

```
conda create --name tf python=3.8 tensorflow 
conda activate tf
```

Comment: Thank you :) it's working. But I am not able to load TF in jupyter notebook

Comment: Check in which environment Jupyter notebook is opened. If its different than the tf environment, fresh install Tensorflow there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally deleted this file. Uninstalling TensorFlow like `pip uninstall tensorflow==2.3.0` and installing it again `pip install tensorflow==2.3.0` resolved the issue. Dont forget to restart the kernal

Answer (score 0):

Adding my workaround/hack (TF `2.5.0`), in case it helps someone:

In my case I already had a dozen of Visual C++ Redistributables installed ('05, '08, ... all the way to 2017) - but TF was still failing with the infamous `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found` error. I didn't want to download and install another redistributable, just to get TF working. (Besides, I had already run into several posts, enough to raise doubt whether installing it would actually resolve the problem.)

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12075042/how-hard-to-reverse-engineer-pyd-files), the offending failing `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd` is just another DLL; so I

1. downloaded (just 468 KB) and ran [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to detect which DLLs were requested by above PYD.
2. in addition to the commonly mentioned `vcruntime140.dll`, the PYD was also depending on a `vcruntime140_1.dll`.
3. `vcruntime140.dll` was available in `C:/Windows/System32/` (checked using `where vcruntime140.dll`), but not `vcruntime140_1.dll`; so I ran a search on my system partition C: and found several copies of `vcruntime140_1.dll` at other places, mainly in my home dir's `AppData/Local/` (user-installed apps).
4. Almost all these apps were "trusted" ones (WhatsApp, MS Teams, ...) so I just copied `vcruntime140_1.dll` from one of them into `C:/Windows/System32/` - and the error went away.

So if you get this error even when all documented requirements are fulfilled, do a bit of debugging to find the *cause* of the error. It will probably save you a good deal of frustration and wasted bandwidth.